# javacard programming and applet installation

Tags: javacard

I am new to javacard programming.While working with owner pin in my javacard application, I referred that "PIN interface which is in javacard framework package does not make any assumptions about where the data for the PIN value comparison is stored".
And I want to know the following,

1. Can I get the exact location where my owner pin is stored? If I can how to do that? How to export my updated owner pin?
2. I have an applet of my javacard application. Now how can I load & install into my javacard.I know there are tools available and come with the smartcard itself. But I want to install without tool and only through apdu commands. Is there any procedure to do that? If so how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sorry, you cannot retrieve the OwnerPIN, probably because of security reasons. You will have to implement the PIN interface yourself if you want to do that, but there are *about 8* pitfalls in the implementation regarding side channel attacks and such. If you can't think of about 8 attacks, don't go there. Generally, retrieving the PIN as data is *not* what you should want.
2. Of course there is a procedure to do that: create your own GlobalPlatform API - you might want to look at open source examples though, such as [gjp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gpj/).

As an extreme hack, you could store the PIN in as the value of a secret key object (which are generally well protected).

Comment: You are welcome! If you think this is the right answer, please vote for it (up arrow) and select it as an answer (the v mark on the left).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the installation of applets I have a good and bad news for you:

The general process of command for installing is standardized by [Global Platform](http://www.globalplatform.org), however that refers only to those commands you send to the Cardmanager-Applet. 
However AFAIK there is no vendor independent standard of the Cardmanager-AID. Additionally you have to authenticate yourself to the Cardmanager applet before you can use it. On developer cards this is usually a simple key like `404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f` (hex) as used for example by JCOP cards for the first DES key.

Additionally this authentication key can be changed by the card owner. Therefore on non-developer cards you don't have access to the Cardmanager.

Comment: Normally the AID is the "RID" of either VISA, `A000000003` (for older implementations, 2.1.1 and before) or that of Global Platform `A000000151`, appended with a number of zero's, two should suffice for AID `A0000000030000` or `A0000001510000` (2.1.1 possibly, and above). Vendors could change that or add their own, I don't know.